# Proving the product topology is discrete iff each component is discrete

Tags: general-topology

> Let $(X_i,T_i),i\in\Bbb N$, be a countably infinite (non-empty) family of topological spaces. Prove that $\prod(X_i,T_i)$ is a discrete space iff each $(X_i,T_i)$ is discrete and all but a finite number of the $X_i,i\in\Bbb N$ are singleton sets.

I think the backward direction is quite trivial so I will just do the forward direction here.

If $(X_i,T_i),i\in\Bbb N$ is discrete, then all singletons or points are open. Now all basic open sets are of the form $U=O_1\times O_2\times\cdots\times O_n×X_{n+1}\times X_{n+2}$ where all but a finite number of the open sets are of the form $X_i$.

How do I go from here to showing that each component is discrete and furthermore all but a finite number of the components are singleton sets?

Comment: This would be easier to read with [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: By "component" I think you mean "factor". A *component* of a topological space is a maximal connected subspace.

Answer (score 1):

Let $=\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}X_n$, and let $x=\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in X$. $X$ is discrete, so $\{x\}$ is open, and there is therefore a basic open set $B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq\{x\}$, i.e., such that $B=\{x\}$. Since $B$ is a basic open set, there are open sets $U_n\subseteq X_n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that

$$\{x\}=B=\prod_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n\,,$$

and there is an $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $U_n=X_n$ for all $n>m$. Clearly $x_n\in U_n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. Suppose that there are an $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ and a $z\in U_n\setminus\{x_n\}$, and let $y=\langle y_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle$ be given by

$$y_k=\begin{cases}
z,&\text{if }k=n\\
x_k,&\text{otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$

Then on the one hand $y_k\in U_k$ for each $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $y\in B$, but on the other hand $y\ne x$, so $y\notin B$. This is impossible, so there is no such point $y$ in $X$, and therefore $U_n\setminus\{x_n\}=\varnothing$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$. $U_n=X_n$ when $n>m$, so for $n>m$ we have $X_n=\{x_n\}$; and for $n\le m$ we have $U_n=\{x_n\}$, so $\{x_n\}$ is open in $X_n$. Thus, at most the first $m$ factor spaces have more than one point.

I leave it to you to finish the job of showing that each $X_n$ with $n\le m$ must have the discrete topology; just pick any $n\le m$ and any point $x_n'\in X_n$, apply the same argument to the point of $X$ obtained from $x$ by changing the $n$-th coordinate to $x_n'$, and conclude that $\{x_n'\}$ is open in $X_n$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if $f: X \to Y$ is open and onto, and $X$ is discrete then $Y$ is discrete too. This is rather trivial to prove.

We can apply this to $X=\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ and the open projections $\pi_i$ to conclude that $X$ discrete implies that all factor are.

Moreover, if $(a_i)_i$ is any point of $X$, then $\{a\}$ is open and so by the definition of the product topology there is a basic open subset $O=\prod_{i \in I} O_i$ of $X$, so all $O_i$ are open and there is a finite subset $F \subseteq I$ such that $O_i = X_i$ for all $ i \notin F$ (I say that $O$ depends on the finite set $F$, usually), and such that $O = \{a\}$ (or $\{a\}$ would not be open).

But then for all $i \in I\setminus F$ (so almost all $i$) we have  $\{a_i\}=\pi_i[\{a\}]= \pi_i[O] = O_i = X_i$ and so all but finitely many of the $X_i$ are singleton sets.

In fact no infinite product of non-singleton spaces can have isolated points.